# Multicomputer USB Switch (KVM without video) that doesn't disconnect devices?

Tags: usb, kvm

I'm looking for the USB side of a KVM switch that does not detach USB devices. I do not want a device that "emulates" a generic keyboard and mouse, but one that maintains the same USB IDs and shows that when not on the active machine the peripherals are still connected and working.

Comment: The function call "HID DDM". DDM is for "Dynamic Device Mapping". Google "DDM-class KVM switch". You should find a matching KVM switch for your applications' needs.

Answer (score 1):

The DDM core of KVM switches can only do most of USB HID devices (such as keyboard, mouse or touch-sensor/controller sharing.)

Normally, there are only two DDM ports will be available on each DDM-class KVM switch - due to the limitation of the DDM chips' capacity.